# Can't add module to Joomla template 3.0.2

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I created a template on the Joomla 3.0.2 platform.The template is alright but I met an error: I can't add any module of Joomla to my template.Example, in file index.php I have a `<div>` tag:

```
 <div id="find"> </div>
```

I want include at this "Search" module, then I insert this code in tag div:

```
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="find" style="xhtml" />
```

Last, I update my templateDetails.xml:

```
 <position> find </position>
```

But when I try to insert the "Search"  module at the "find" position, it doesn't work, please help me fix this.

Comment: Can you add the module in other templates?

Comment: Yes, I can add any module to all other templates but except this template, you can see my code at this link : http://www.mediafire.com/?7t5pv4v2xtd5ux7 . Can you help me fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following problems in your template:

1. In your manifest file `<position> find </position>` is not the same with `<position>find</position>`, so remove the whitespace. As a general rule, don't use whitespace between tags (in XML as well in XHTML).
2. Each folder should contain an empty index.html file.
3. Do not use absolute paths to link CSS and images.

Have a very close look at how Protostar template is build, you may learn a lot of things from there.

Comment: Thank you very much !, I fixed this error, I hope get many tips from you ^^.